# BCrypt generate hash and salt then compare to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm looking to BCrypt to hash and salt and compare it to the hash stored in my database. There seems to be a lack of vb.net with BCrypt, which is why I'm asking.

So, from what I understand is we generate a hash and a salt when the user enters their password. Then we compare that hash to the one in the database, however since I've found nothing online for vb.net I'm not sure how to do it.

This is what I have so far. If the code looks messy it's because I copied and pasted it from Visual Studio to here, on VS it looks neat and tidy.

Now I know there will be flaws with the code etc. I'm not that bothered as this is for personal use and learning. Just need to learn how to generate salt + hash with BCrypt and then compare it with the already hash & salted password in my database but in terms of how to go about and redo this bit of code and implement the check that both salt & hashes are the same I'm stuck.

```
Dim pw As String = TextBox_Password.Text
Dim Salt As String = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12)
Dim Hash As String = BCryot.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(pw, salt)

Try
Connection.Open()
Dim SQLQuery
SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM `core_members` where name='" & TextBox_Username & " ' and members_pass_hash='" & I don't know if you're meant to put Hash? here to hash the inputed password from the user? Or the TextBox_Password.Text & "'"

'As for the verify function... to compare the hashed password I do try to do this

If (BCRYpt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(pw, hash)) Then
Command1 = New MySqlCommand(SQLQuery, Connection)
READER = Command1.ExecuteReader

Dim Count As Integer
count = 0
While READER.read
count += 1
end while

READER.close()

If count = 1 then

'User Successfully Logged In

end if

'I definitely know the count = 1 etc probably not the best way to allow a user to login. I've seen something with MyData.HasRows or something like that to login?

'I know that the code above is probably no where near close to actually how it's done but as I said due to the lack of documentation with vb.net and BCrypt not making it easy.
```

Any help with cleaning up the login function would be great including comparing the hashed password in my database.

Comment: It looks like you have SQL injection in you first query. I appreciate you may know this already, but someone may be tempted to copy your code in six months time.

Comment: You have `BCryot.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword` (which looks like it has a typo) and `BCRYpt.Net.BCrypt.Verify` (which looks like it has case errors). Does this code actually work?

Comment: @halfer No, the code I used above doesn't work. I already knew it wouldn't work but I wanted to come up with something to be able to show what I'm trying to do. Theirs not much documentation with vb.net and BCrypt

Comment: @halfer Yeah no thanks! I did notice it when retyping the code out on here. I've already changed it to avoid SQLInjection :)

Comment: OK. So please amend the code here, ideally by copying and pasting it from the code you are actually using. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Sql Server to test code because it was what I had handy. It will work the same for MySql. With BCrypt you don't have to store the salt separately.

```
Private Sub InsertNewUser()
    Dim HashWord As String = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(TextBox2.Text, BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12))
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.PublishCon),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert Into Users (UserName, Password) Values (@Name, @HashWord);", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@HashWord", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = HashWord
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub VerifyPassword()
    Dim pw As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim HashWord As String = ""
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.PublishCon),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Password FROM Users where UserName= @UserName;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        cn.Open()
        HashWord = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString
    End Using
    Dim result = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(pw, HashWord)
    If result Then
        MessageBox.Show("Successful Login")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry login failed")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, however I'm using a forum software called Invision Community and it already hashes and salts the users password, so I need to hash and salt the password they put in the textbox and match it. I'm not sure how BCrypt works, if you're meant to salt and hash the password and then verify it or if you can just use verify and match it with the text in the textbox. I tried using your example but I get a few errors. First on beig execute scalar gives me the error "Input String was in a Correct Format." And If I remove that line it gives me invalid salt

Comment: Also I get a warning with cmd.Parameters.Add it says Public Overloads Function Add (ParameterName As String, value As Object) As MySqlParameter is obsolete. (String ParameterName, Object Value) has been deprecated. Use AddWithValue(StringParameterName, Object Value. I use with AddWithValue but I don't know if it will then work.

Comment: Did you change every occurance of Sql to MySql. SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDbType. Did you check your database for the size and datatype of the fields? Did you change the Insert to you table name and your field names? I will need to see the actual code you used to understand your errors. This code has been tested. Add your new code to your question using the edit link below the question.

Comment: Yup! I got it working about 10 minutes after posting that message. I realised I need to put MySqlCommand and MySqlDbType. Those were causing the errors. Just a quick question about BCrypt is that just to 100% Confirm you only need `BCrypt.Verify(pw, hashword)` and it does it all for you? We don't need to hash and salt the password ourself the verify function does it all for us?

Comment: Yes, thought so. Thank you very much for your help! I've been searching for an answer to this for quite a while, so thank you. I have another question I would love for you to explain to me on how to do it. Should I make a new topic?

Answer (score 1):

Just want to give the biggest thanks to @Mary for being so kind and helpful for providing a solution to solve my biggest problem thus far! Thank you!

I'm only making this Answer because for me there were a few typo's I had to fix, but all of it goes to Mary!

So, first off I'm using a mysql.dat.dll which uses Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient (Which changes a few things from Mary's code)

Imports Crypt = BCRypt.Net.BCrypt - Allows us to use Crypt Instead of having to type the whole BCrypt.Net.BCrypt

Please note for me, if your textbox's are empty then you will get an error Object Reference not set to an instance of an object. This is if you're on visual studio. It won't happen if you run the program as a normal user. I will tell the user make sure they have entered a username and password

```
Imports Crypt = BCRypt.Net.BCrypt

Private Sub VerifyPassword()
try
  Dim Password As String = "TextBox_UserPassword"
  Dim Hashword As String = ""

Using Conn As New MySqlCommand(Connection),
    Command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT password FROM members where Username= @Username;", Conn)
    Command.Parameters.Add("@Username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox_Username
    Conn.Open()
    Hashword = Command.ExecuteScalar.ToString
End Using

Dim Result = Crypt.Verify(Password, Hashword)

If result = true then
    MsgBox("Logged in")
else
    MsgBox("Logged in Failed") 
end if

Catch ex As Exception
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) 'Optional'
   MsgBox("Make sure have entered a Username or Password", vbcritical) 'If the textbox have nothing it will remind the user to make sure they enter a username or password'

End try

End Sub
```

Comment: Upvote for the use of assigned Imports. You shouldn't use exception handling for expected errors. Do validation first instead `If TextBox1.Text =""` Exception handling is rather heavy and should be used for errors beyond your control like a connection that won't work because the server is down. BTW, happy to help.

Comment: @Mary Thanks for the info! Will be sure to remove that. Gotta question I've seen that you can grab an image from a database. I have a column in my database which is this has this line here `monthly_2020_04/ProfilePic.png.a13607537479ed7a0a56fa0090d9d0e7.png` off the database. Is it possible to grab the image of the database? I've not looked into it how it's done but if it is possible then I'll look into it.

Comment: That appears to be a path to an image file. This is an entirely new question on a different topic. Please ask a new question.